# AWS infrastructure for debugging

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, staging

I've made an AWS serverless application with Lambda. I made it and tested it a lot before using in production, so mistakes were allowed in development process. It entered a stable state, so that I didn't make any update to the app since it entered production (almost 1 year). After all this time, I'm willing to improve it in several aspects. The problem is that it's not only Lambda. If it were only Lambda I could easily test in localhost, as it's python. However, it uses also API Gateway, SQS, Dynamo, CloudWatch, and I can't simply mix the development app with the production infrastructure.

The question, thus, is: is there a easy way to make a AWS development infrastructure (like a staging one, copy of the production) with no risk of breaking production?

Obs. I'm currently using Terraform for infrastructure management.

Comment: One manual way is to create copies of all the AWS resources in another account or region. You can test your lambda code using these resources before moving it to production.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use CloudFormation to re-create your entire stack and deploy to another region.  Another, more complex solution would be to use something like docker an SAM local to spin up all instances - but i can't speak to that option.

Comment: I think this is it. I'm not using CloudFormation, but it can be easily done with Terraform too, simply changing the region.